# Dgraph: create edge without prior knowledge of uid

Tags: dgraph

I'm experimenting with dgraph and so far my biggest struggle is to create an edge between two objects without prior knowledge of their uids (for bulk loading).
Example - let's have two types - parent and child, the only difference is that child is always a leaf node, so the schema may be something like

```
<name>: string .
<age>: int .
<children>: [uid] .

type Parent {
    name
    age
    children
}

type Child {
    name
    age
}
```

Now I would like to insert three nodes - two parents and one child - and create an edge between them, all that using one query, without prior querying uid. I imagine something like this:

```
{
    "set": [
        {
            "name": "Kunhuta",
            "age": 38,
            "dgraph.type": "Parent"
        },
        {
            "name": "Vendelin",
            "age": 41,
            "dgraph.type": "Parent"
        },
        {
            "name": "Ferko",
            "age": 14,
            "dgraph.type": "Child",
            "Parent": [
                {
                    "name": "Kunhuta"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Vendelin"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

(Suppose names are unique type identifiers)

Is it possible to somehow do so in dgraph?

Answer (score 0):

So if you are adding new nodes to the graph and wish to connect them to each other with new edges you can do this with blank nodes.

From the dgraph docs: https://dgraph.io/docs/v1.0.8/mutations/

> Blank nodes in mutations, written _:identifier, identify nodes within a mutation

Here's your example with blank nodes added:

```
{
    "set": [
        {
            "uid": "_:kunhuta",
            "name": "Kunhuta",
            "age": 38,
            "dgraph.type": "Parent"
        },
        {
            "uid": "_:vendelin",
            "name": "Vendelin",
            "age": 41,
            "dgraph.type": "Parent"
        },
        {
            "uid": "_:ferko",
            "name": "Ferko",
            "age": 14,
            "dgraph.type": "Child",
            "Parent": [
                {
                    "uid": "_:kunhuta",
                    "name": "Kunhuta"
                },
                {
                    "uid": "_:vendelin",
                    "name": "Vendelin"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Things get a bit more difficult when you want to connect a new node to an existing one in the graph. For example say you committed the above mutation then you wanted to add a new child to "Kunhuta". You would need to query the existing `uid` of "Kunhuta" and use that uid on a new set mutation to add your child.

Also I would use some form of unique identifier outside of names to help query for the `uid`. If you ended up adding another "Kunhuta" in your graph how would you know which is the real parent? For this reason dgraph recommends adding an external identifier (usually a uuid) and calling it `xid` in your schema.